# How to remove duplicate images from wordpress post ? my blog post shows same images multiples how it will be fixed

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming, blogs, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using Automotive Car Dealership Business WordPress Theme my blog page is showing duplicate images in my blog post I edited all posts there is no feautred and double image but still double images are showing on my blog page. please explain how to fix this issue without using any plugin.
link of my blog post page
https://www.motoringinvestments.com/news/

Answer (score 1):

Please try Deactivating Jetpack Plugin and check if the issue exists.
It seems like the Jetpack Plugin is loading Jetpack-lazy-image, try turing it off and see.

Comment: thank you so much Mr, Mahmud Hasan issue is resolved.